# What do we call people who are into various sports?

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english, british-english, sports

What do we call someone who is into different sports including biking, mountaineering, tracking, and other similar sports?

Comment: The word "freak" is often used informally to mean someone who is an enthusiast about something, and is listed in dictionaries in this way. You could call them a sports freak.

Answer (score 1):

a **multisport** athlete  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/multisport)

> 2. Skilled in several sports: a multisport athlete.

and

> An athlete who competes in more than one sport—e.g., swimming,
>   cycling, running—usually in sequence; often the individual sports are
>   practised separately and raced jointly.  [TFD](https://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/Multisport+Athlete)

As in:

“Your child should be a **multisport** athlete!”  [USA Today](https://usatodayhss.com/2017/a-few-surprises-in-the-data-behind-single-sport-and-multisport-athletes)

Comment: I think OP had in mind a focus on the outdoor adventure sports whereas a multisport athlete could be one who plays basketball and baseball.

Comment: @Jim noted and edited

Answer (score 1):

I would call them [sporty](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sporty):

> **sporty**
>
> ADJECTIVE
>
> *informal*
>
> 1 Fond of or good at sport.

However, "sporty" isn't only applied to people but to objects as well, such as cars and clothes.

Answer (score 0):

Calling them an athlete is suitable enough in most cases, if they play competitively. Some triathlons include those sports so triathlete could be another more specific way to describe them. Again, these suggestions are leaning more towards actively competing versus something like a hobby.

Comment: Hi harada, welcome to English Language & Usage. Note that this site is a bit different from other Q&A sites: an answer is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct* - preferably by quoting a reference (e.g. dictionary definition) hyperlinked to the source. You can [edit] your post to add this detail; for further guidance, see [answer]. :-)

Answer (score -1):

I'd call them an *outdoor enthusiast*.

Comment: Please note, the system has flagged your answer for deletion as "low-quality because of its **length** and **content**." An answer on this site is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct*. You can [edit] your answer to avoid deletion - for example, citing published examples or definitions, linked to the source. For further guidance, see [answer].